# How to get the bundle product options via SOAP api?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, bundled-product, soap-api-v2

This one is making me feel right stupid!

I can see how to add product options when creating a product over the API, as catalogProductCustomOptionAdd describes fields for options like sku etc.

But I don't want to add, i just want to make product information available - and here when I look at my product information over soap... i can't seem to get options for my bundles

`catalogProductCustomOptionList` (or more precisely `$client->catalogProductCustomOptionList($sess_id, $productid,1);` )  returns empty `array(0) {}`

my basic product information clearly reports it has options: `$client->catalogProductInfo($sess_id, $productid)` correctly returns `["has_options"]=> string(1) "1"`

so where are they?

What am I missing, What's the way to get the options from a bundle?

Or is it another thing not available in API?

Comment: programatically in my modules I can get the options for example via 

`$childProducts = Mage::getModel('bundle/product_type')->getSelectionsCollection($mainproduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($mainproduct),$mainproduct);`  and in phtml templates they show fine too, so they exist!

Comment: I also can see them in the REST API, dammit, so why not in the SOAP one?